# Animate element on scroll and pause animation if scrolling stops

Tags: css, animation, scroll, animate.css, wow.js

I am trying to animate some elements with css animations on a page when scrolling occurs and I wish to pause these animations if user stops scrolling. This [Sony be moved](https://www.sony.com/be-moved/) website illustrates the effect I am trying to achieve quite well. However, this specific one uses a video which is not ideal for me. I was wondering if there is a way to achieve the same effect with only css animations. I had a look at the wow.js script. However, it's not quite what I am looking for as the elements animations do not "pause" when scrolling stops. I don't have ny code to share as I did not manage to make it even slightly work as I wish. Any advice on this would be appreciated.

Comment: SO is not really the place for recommendations, but check out Skrollr, it gives very fine-grained control over the position of all elements in the page as it scrolls.

Comment: Ok. Thank you very much!